# R rbind & write.table: paragraphs seem to change; Word seems to not recognize paragraphs anymore

Tags: r, vba, ms-word, rbind, write.table

I have the following problem. I have many text files that need to be tidied up for further processing. I recorded a VBA code in word for one of the files which worked. I used R's readr, rbind and write.table to merge my text documents into just one file, and wanted to then use Word's VBA I had recorded for cleaning (I am not good with regex in r). That's the code in R, here with just two files as example:

```
library(readr)
temp = list.files(pattern="*txt")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read_file(temp[i]))
total <- rbind(`Chinese (1).txt`,`Chinese (2).txt`)
write.table(total, "mymatrix.txt", fileEncoding = "UTF-8", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

The problem I now encounter is that something must have happened to the paragraph at one specific point, which means that my VBA doesn't recognize the paragraphs anymore even though it should do so. This shows a new word file which illustrates how the original file looks different compared to my work-around from R :

[image: Comparison between the original file and how it gets written from R]

The VBA code I used on this example is:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

which leads to this result:

[image]

What happened? How do I fix this? The best I can think of is to just copy paste the various Chinese files into one, but eventually there will be many more, so I was hoping to use rbind to decrease the likelihood of mistakes.

Comment: It's not clear what result you're expecting? All on one line (which is what I expect the VBA code to do)? Fact is, Word expects ANSI 13 (carriage return) to represent a paragraph mark. Many programs use ANSI 13 + ANSI 10, which Word doesn't always deal with gracefully. Can you find out what characters are being used by r to produce these files?

Comment: It seems that R adds characters (perhaps Chr(10) as Cindy has suggested, perhaps a space (not necessarily Chr(32)). The effect would be that you don't have `^p^p` and therefore can't find it. Perhaps `^p*^p` might work.